# Create file unreadable to user

Tags: windows, file-permissions

Is there a way to make a file that is not readable to anyone else other than the Windows system, even if it is transferred to another Windows machine? I mean not allowing it to be opened with a text editing program if it's from a regular user.

Comment: If you can't read it, you can't transfer it to another computer.

Comment: Asking for the impossible. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Why? What is the use case? Who is creating the file and who will work on it? Things to keep in mind: 1. if backup should work, don't forget to include rights for the backup operators, 2. admins can take ownership of the file and then modify the rights. What transfer of files are you talking about? If files can be copied to another machine using standard Windows mechanisms (network or memory stick) you have no influence on the rights on the target system.

Comment: The use case would be a program that would want to hide its internals from the user and only show selected output. It was a program I was asked to create, for starters see if it can be created.. I did sound pretty difficult to me too, but I asked anyway just in case.

Comment: The A#1 use for this would be for a password vault.  If you could make it so that the program is non-automatable, and the file difficult to read by anything but the password vault program, that would help close the vulnerabilities that involve malware stealing/driving your password vault.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create the file as Administrator, and then set its [permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) to remove all permissions for all groups other than Administrator.

That way, regular users (eg. non administrators) will not be able to read it.

I can't answer about the transfer if you don't give more details about how you plan to transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

It may be difficult to tighten the permissions all the way, but you can get a ways towards the *nix scheme with setuid programs.  If you change ownership of a file to another user (disabled, no logins allowed), disable read permissions for everyone but that user, and run your program under the credentials of that user with runas, that should help protect the file from prying eyes.  There doesn't seem to be any way to do this with a non-interactive user, however, which would be a good solution to preventing interactive access to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring information from a sender to a receiver in a secret fashion, that is what encryption was invented for about [3.500 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cryptography).

If you write a file to an USB drive and set it so be only readable by a certain user, that is like writing a message on a piece of paper prepended by instructions that this paper may only be read by the intended receiver. That already did not proof to be secure thousand of years ago.

Instead, I would recommend to use [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/).